# How to obtain the second derivative using parametric differentiation?

Tags: sympy

If I have two parametric equations, e.g. `x = 2*t` and `y = t**2 - 3`, I can differentiate them as follows:

```python
>>> x, y, t = symbols('x, y, t')
>>> x = 2*t
>>> y = t**2 - 3
>>> diff(y)/diff(x)
t
```

To obtain the second derivative:

```python
>>> (diff(x,t,1)*diff(y,t,2) - diff(y,t,1)*diff(x,t,2)) / diff(x,t,1)**3
1/2
```

Is there a shortcut within sympy that I can use to calculate this?

Maybe wrapping this in a function is what I should be doing?

```python
>>> def second_derivative(x,y):  
>>>   return (diff(x,t,1)*diff(y,t,2) - diff(y,t,1)*diff(x,t,2)) / diff(x,t,1)**3
```

Then it becomes:

```python
>>> second_derivative(2*t, t**2 - 3)
1/2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went with creating a custom function:

```python
>>> def second_derivative(x,y):  
>>>   return (diff(x,t,1)*diff(y,t,2) - diff(y,t,1)*diff(x,t,2)) / diff(x,t,1)**3
```

Which is called like this:

```python
>>> second_derivative(2*t, t**2 - 3)
1/2
```

Comment: The downvote was apparently because the downvoter did not like that the answer contains some of the same information as the question.